# How to search dynamic elements of array in ElasticSearch using C# NEST?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have these data in my elasticsearch with this structure.

[image]

How do I search firstName, middleName and surname from this array? Note: The `NameDetails` array length is dynamic. Person A could have just one element of `NameDetails`. Person B could have 3 elements of `NameDetails`.

At the moment, I could only search by `gender`. I am using NEST nuget C#. This is my query.

```
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Person>(s => s
          .Query(q => q
              .Bool(b => b.Must(
                mu => mu
                .Match(m => m
                 .Field(f => f.Gender)
                 .Query(Gender)
                )

                )
              )
          )
        );
```

[image]

In NEST, I tried with this code but return no result.

```
        var response = _elasticClient.Search <Model.Entities.Split.Person.Person> (s => s
            .Index("person")
            .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.NameDetails.Name[0].NameValue.FirstName)
                    .Query("Fawsu")
                )
            )
        );
```

But if I directly run the DSL query at ElasticSearch with query below, it returns result.

```
GET /person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
          "nameDetails.nameValue.firstName": {
            "query": "Fawsu"
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
GET /person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "nameDetails.nameValue.surname": {
              "value": "Pibba",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        },
        
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "nameDetails.nameValue.firstName": {
              "value": "Fawsu",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's useful to see how this is mapped to a POCO

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string ActiveStatus { get; set; }
    public string Deceased { get; set; }
    public List<Name> NameDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public List<NameValue> NameValue { get; set; }
    public string NameType { get; set; }
}

public class NameValue
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

*(You might map some of these fields as types other than string, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader).*

To search on first name

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();


var response = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .Index("people")
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.NameDetails[0].NameValue[0].FirstName)
            .Query("Fawsu")
        )
    )
);
```

which yields the query

```json
POST http://localhost:9200/people/_search?pretty=true&typed_keys=true 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "nameDetails.nameValue.firstName": {
        "query": "Fawsu"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The expression in `.Field(f => f...)` is an expression to build the path to `"nameDetails.nameValue.firstName"`, which will look for a match in **any** first name of name value and name details. The fact it uses indexers does **not** mean that it is targeting the first name value of the first name details, but are simply a way to traverse the object graph to build the expression.

To build a composite query to target multiple values of the **same** name value, both `Name` and `NameValue` would need to be [mapped as `nested` data types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), and then nested queries would be used.

For a single field

```cs
var response = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .Index("people")
    .Query(q => q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(f => f.NameDetails)
            .Query(nq => nq
                .Nested(nn => nn
                    .Path(f => f.NameDetails[0].NameValue)
                    .Query(nnq => nnq
                        .Match(m => m
                            .Field(f => f.NameDetails[0].NameValue[0].FirstName)
                            .Query("Fawsu")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

For multiple fields

```cs
var response = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .Index("people")
    .Query(q => q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(f => f.NameDetails)
            .Query(nq => nq
                .Nested(nn => nn
                    .Path(f => f.NameDetails[0].NameValue)
                    .Query(nnq => nnq
                        .Bool(b => b
                            .Must(m => m
                                .Match(m => m
                                    .Field(f => f.NameDetails[0].NameValue[0].FirstName)
                                    .Query("Fawsu")
                                ), m => m
                                .Match(m => m
                                    .Field(f => f.NameDetails[0].NameValue[0].LastName)
                                    .Query("Pibba")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

the latter of which results in the query

```json
POST http://localhost:9200/people/_search?pretty=true&typed_keys=true 
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "nameDetails",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "nameDetails.nameValue",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "nameDetails.nameValue.firstName": {
                      "query": "Fawsu"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "nameDetails.nameValue.lastName": {
                      "query": "Pibba"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The solutions looks good. Just wondering, how do I check whether it is mapped as nested data types?

Comment: You can get the index mapping and check the type for the field: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html. Here's the get mapping API test for NEST: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/f0c45f49e9cab586b65f55b361966dc4d4453418/tests/Tests/Indices/MappingManagement/GetMapping/GetMappingApiTest.cs#L51-L76. It uses a visitor over fields to assert mapping type counts, but you can traverse to the properties directly on the response and assert the type

Comment: I have updated to add a print screen of my mapping. I notice that even though the type of `text`, I can query it. About the NEST code, if I just specify to just array index zero, will it search through other array elements? Because one person could have multiple set of names.

Comment: Please copy and paste code/text rather than screenshots - it's easier to read, work with, and is indexable/searchable. It looks like both `nameDetails` and `nameValue` are mapped as [`"object"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html), which is OK if you want to search for single fields in isolation but will not work if you want to search across fields of the same `nameDetail` or `nameValue`.

Comment: The expression `.Field(f => f.NameDetails[0].NameValue[0].FirstName)` will search through all first names of all name values and all name details

Comment: How do I translate my query into NEST syntax?

Comment: which query? do the examples here help?

Comment: I posted a new post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66864524/return-no-result-for-nest-c-sharp-but-query-dsl-return-result

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search something like:

*firstName == "John" AND middleName == "Ben" AND lastName == "smith"*

Then you can use [TermQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-query-usage.html) to search `firstName`, `middleName` and `lastName`:

I am more familiar with *Object Initializer Syntax* (which requires `using static Nest.Infer`)

```
using static Nest.Infer;

var query = new TermQuery
{
    Name = "my firstName query",
    Field = Field<Person>(p => p.firstName),
    Value = "John"
};
```

You would need to write 2 more queries for `middleName` and `lastName` and then `AND` all of these queries.

---

If you want to search something like:

*firstName == "John" OR middleName == "John" OR lastName == "John"*

Then you can use [Multi-match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html):

```
using static Nest.Infer;

var query = new MultiMatchQuery
{
    Name = "My Multi-match query",
    Fields = Field<Person>(p => p.firstName, 1.1) // 1.1 is boost (default is 1)
        .And<AdDocument>(p => p.middleName, 1)
        .And<AdDocument>(p => p.lastName, 1)
    Query = "John"
    //Fuzziness = Fuzziness.Auto
};
```

Comment: But firstname is nested in `nameDetails`. Basically, one person could have many set of names. Example, the person I posted has 2 set of names, firstName: Fawsu and surName: Pibba AND firstName: Fausu and surName: Pibba.