# Return no result for NEST C# but Query DSL return result

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have this Query DSL which return the correct result when I query directly at ElasticSearch

```
GET /person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
          "nameDetails.nameValue.firstName": {
            "query": "Fawsu"
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But in NEST C#, it doesn't return any result. May I know what's wrong with my syntax?

```
        var response = _elasticClient.Search<Person> (s => s
            .Index("person")
            .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.NameDetails.Name.First().NameValue.FirstName)
                    .Query("Fawsu")
                )
            )
        );
```

or

```
        var response = _elasticClient.Search<Person> (s => s
            .Index("person")
            .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.NameDetails.Name[0].NameValue.FirstName)
                    .Query("Fawsu")
                )
            )
        );
```

How do I see the query generated by NEST to troubleshoot this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in `.Field(f => f.NameDetails.Name[0].NameValue.FirstName)` looks like it has an extra level, `Name`, to the object graph compared to the expected string. I would expect the output of the expression would be

```
nameDetails.name.nameValue.firstName
```

which will not match the field `"nameDetails.nameValue.firstName"` in the query.

[You can see what NEST sends to Elasticsearch in a number of ways](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/troubleshooting.html)

Comment: I am using the same class for both indexing and searching. Not sure why `Name` is missing during indexing

Comment: Problem solved. Actually I use another class for index and another class for search. Thanks Russ.